# How to work once setTimeout function that in keypress function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, settimeout, onkeypress

I want to my keypress fuction works every press but setTimeout dosen't work. here is my html and scripts;

**html:**

```
    <div  id="fake" class="full-height col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="nav-right">
            <div class="form-search">
                <input  id="fake-search" onkeypress="dialogTrigger(event)" class="fake-search" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**scripts:**

```
function dialogTrigger(event) {
    var keyboardInput = event.which;
    keyboardInput = keyboardInput + 5;
    var changedInput = String.fromCharCode(keyboardInput);
    $("#fake-search").val($("#fake-search").val() + changedInput);
    setTimeout(function () {
       doSomething(); // about html
    }, 10000);
}
```

Comment: try writing on onkeyup event

Comment: setTimeout function in onkeyup didnt work only once. I tried but thnx.

Comment: You need to use  var timeout = setTimeout. Then u need to decide if every time the key is pressed you need to cancel the timeout and start another one or leave the current one to fire in which case don't overwrite. Right now you are going to fire your dialog multiple times.

Comment: It would be work. Please try `alert("DO SOMETHING")` before `doSomething();` and wait 10s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to decide what the logic is. If the idea is to throttle a dialog open once after 10 seconds then you would need to do something like this

```
var to;
function dialogTrigger(event) {
    var keyboardInput = event.which;
    keyboardInput = keyboardInput + 5;
    var changedInput = String.fromCharCode(keyboardInput);
    $("#fake-search").val($("#fake-search").val() + changedInput);

    // The line below will only start the timer if none exists;

    to = to || setTimeout(function () {
       doSomething(); // about html
    }, 10000);
}
```

On the other hand if you want to only open the dialog after they finish typing

```
 var to;
    function dialogTrigger(event) {
        var keyboardInput = event.which;
        keyboardInput = keyboardInput + 5;
        var changedInput = String.fromCharCode(keyboardInput);
        $("#fake-search").val($("#fake-search").val() + changedInput);

        // The line below clear any existing timeout and start a new one

        if (to) clearTimeout(to);
        to =  setTimeout(function () {
           doSomething(); // about html
        }, 10000);
    }
```

Note 10000ms is about 10 seconds

Comment: Thnx a lot! I just want to a dialog open once after 10 seconds. First one working correctly.